# How to resolve error message: could not find function "gls"

Tags: r

I am using the "ape" package to run a phylogenetic gls, but I am stumped by an error message: could not find function "gls". Does anyone please know how to resolve this? Thank you.

```
tree <- tree.primates 
bm.prim <- corBrownian(phy=tree) 
XY <- data.frame(Y, X) 
summary(gls(Y ~ X, correlation=corBrownian(phy=tree), data=XY))
```

Comment: It would help dramatically to see the code that actually produced this error...

Comment: it's a shot in the dark, but try `library(ape)` before you call the function :)

Comment: Here is the code that I am working with. Not sure how much to include, but thank you for looking:

Comment: > tree <- tree.primates
> bm.prim <- corBrownian(phy=tree)
> XY <- data.frame(Y, X)
> summary(gls(Y ~ X, correlation=corBrownian(phy=tree), data=XY))

Comment: Try using `library(nlme)` at the beginning of your code.

Comment: Thank you RHertel for your help. That resolved this issue. Thanks to all.

Comment: @RHertel can you elaborate why the nlme package is needed here?

Comment: Because the `gls` function is in the `nlme` package.

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/nlme/html/gls.html

Answer (score 0):

`ape` does not have a `gls` function. You'll need to load a package that has the implementation you want, probably `nlme`, though apparently a package called `QTLRel` has one as well.

[Here are my search results on rdocumentation.org](http://www.rdocumentation.org/advanced_search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=&package_name=&function_name=gls&title=&description=&author=) which is where I found the packages that have `gls` functions.